# How should one add UML diagrams to the question or answer?

Tags: discussion

How can I efficiently paste [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagrams on Stack Overflow?

Usually, when I have some simple question I can of course draw it in ASCII format, but it's not efficient for me.

I can paste images made by some diagramming tools or even paint, but then different users would have different styles of pasting diagrams (as they use different tools).

Is there any good (preferred) way by Stack Overflow to add UML diagrams?

Comment: Why do you feel that the UML diagrams would improve the quality of your answer, as well as make it more accessible for others?  Just a question, really; you could always just put the images into the answer if you liked.

Comment: @Makoto Do you think it helps in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424503/1168342

Comment: @Fuhrmanator:  It *does*...but I'm concerned about the question material itself.

Comment: @makato I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean by `the question material`. Is it the question here or the question of the answer I referred to.

Comment: https://www.draw.io/

Comment: @Fuhrmanator He probably means that that question was probably more suited to, e.g., Programmers.SE than StackOverflow.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk:  Actually, Bakuriu had it more correct.  The question doesn't seem on-topic here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com), which allows making diagrams in a text-based language (see the [reference guide](http://plantuml.com/PlantUML_Language_Reference_Guide.pdf)). For example, the following code will produce the diagram for the Adapter pattern found in the GoF:

```
skinparam style strictuml
hide empty members
interface Target {
  {abstract} Request()
}
class Adapter implements Target {
  Request()
}
note right of Adapter::Request
SpecificRequest()
end note
class Adaptee {
  SpecificRequest()
}

Adaptee <|-down- Adapter : (implementation)

class Client {
}
Client -r-> Target
```

### Create the diagram online

[PlantUML.com has a web page to do this](http://plantuml.com/plantuml/), but I prefer [PlantText.com's editor](http://www.planttext.com/planttext).

[image: Screen capture for PlantText.com]

Copy (e.g. via right-click) the hyperlink to the SVG image (in yellow above) or alternatively the PNG image (greater compatibility but limited resolution and no textual information).

Then it's a matter of pasting that URL as a *link to an image* in a posting.

```
![UML class diagram of (class) Adapter pattern from GoF](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/POzH2i8m38RVSueypeTTO8WWta2zGEooBTXsjOs8wEvkbMrEV0aXVD-V99t51uhaCEdTSgvHZ5wTXKvgHdP1x-ZOdJWc4AyS6pACHuejApu0yK6dB97H0VTykNBIOWK364ifuRQca1qK5omxzfgMwfBtlJ96QJl5lfcygXeHE0GsqeZvAknhV4i_c_YJ-myF01EmVfPrV_FbV5k5nNmUgVH-1MFcpagUvSW1nhQCvMRyu0K0)
```

The above inserted into a post on stack exchange gives us:

[image: UML class diagram of (class) Adapter pattern from GoF]

### Link to the image on PlantUML.com

The reason I link to the UML image on PlantUML.com is that you can edit it later. If you use the Stack Exchange upload image feature (copy/paste image), the image will be uploaded to imgur.com (like the screen shot in this post) and you won't be able to get back the PlantUML source code.

Inside the PlantUML.com URL is an encoded key of the source code used to generate the diagram. For example, using the code above, I get:
    https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/POzH2i8m38RVSueypeTTO8WWta2zGEooBTXsjOs8wEvkbMrEV0aXVD-V99t51uhaCEdTSgvHZ5wTXKvgHdP1x-ZOdJWc4AyS6pACHuejApu0yK6dB97H0VTykNBIOWK364ifuRQca1qK5omxzfgMwfBtlJ96QJl5lfcygXeHE0GsqeZvAknhV4i_c_YJ-myF01EmVfPrV_FbV5k5nNmUgVH-1MFcpagUvSW1nhQCvMRyu0K0

Everything after the `https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/` is the encoded key of the source. If you take that part of the URL and go back to one of the web editors mentioned above, you can get back the source.

For PlantText.com it's `http://www.planttext.com/planttext?text=KEY` or using the example above,
http://www.planttext.com/planttext?text=POzH2i8m38RVSueypeTTO8WWta2zGEooBTXsjOs8wEvkbMrEV0aXVD-V99t51uhaCEdTSgvHZ5wTXKvgHdP1x-ZOdJWc4AyS6pACHuejApu0yK6dB97H0VTykNBIOWK364ifuRQca1qK5omxzfgMwfBtlJ96QJl5lfcygXeHE0GsqeZvAknhV4i_c_YJ-myF01EmVfPrV_FbV5k5nNmUgVH-1MFcpagUvSW1nhQCvMRyu0K0

Comment: Is PlantUML supposed to be used this way? By direct-linking to 'images' on their site, this can generate lots of traffic for them. Do you know if they are OK with this use?

Comment: Lots of long URLs... 0_o  Had almost gone to flag spam :P

Comment: So, does that mean the image can change out from under the post at any time? That's bad...

Comment: @MicroVirus PlantUML re-tweets my tweets about how to do these things on GitHub as well as SO. See https://twitter.com/PlantUML for a re-tweet of this answer. I developed a Google Docs Add-on called PlantUML Gizmo two years ago, which "hot links" to their site. The editor at PlantText.com hot-links to their site, etc.

Comment: @Deduplicator The PlantUML.com server is serving the image from a URL that contains hashed source code. The service could go down, and the image would not appear (but so could imgur.com where stackoverflow stores its images when you upload them). The text-to-hash algorithm used by PlantUML.com is deterministic and reversible. So, I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @BhargavRao PlantUML has some jquery support described at http://plantuml.com/jquery.html. Perhaps one day the markdown in SO could be modified to support it (so we could type the source inside SO and it would render automatically with no long URLs). As for the long URLs, they aren't so problematic when you get used to it. You copy the URL from the online editor, then type `![name]()` paste the URL between the parentheses.

Comment: If it's *reversible*, it isn't a hash. And SE has a deal with imgur, so while they may suffer a short-lived outage, that's the worst that could happen to the images. But thanks for the assurance that they don't allow changing an image in-place.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Fair enough. That was meant to be fun comment only.

Comment: @Deduplicator indeed, I should have said encoding with compression.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://gravizo.com/ it's made for that:

> a simple way of describing graphs and include it easily in your web
>   for free, blog, markdown page, github, and any location where remote
>   images can be showed. Gravizo uses Graphviz to render graphs. It
>   supports DOT, PlantUML, UMLGraph syntax and SVG in JSON format. It
>   will include other formats in the future. No javascript, no plugins
>   needed so you can include in any document.

It supports the plantuml syntax.

You can use its page to edit and preview the diagrams then copy the resulting image url into stackoverflow like:

```
![Alt](https://gravizo.com/g?[mangled-version-of-your-uml-diagram])
```

[image: Alt]

And to copy another example :)

```
![Alt](https://gravizo.com/g?/***Structural%20Things*@opt%20commentname*@note%20Notes%20can*be%20extended%20to*span%20multiple%20lines*/class%20Structural{}/***@opt%20all*@note%20Class*/class%20Counter%20extends%20Structural%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20public%20int%20counter;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20int%20getCounter%28%29;}/***@opt%20shape%20activeclass*@opt%20all*@note%20Active%20Class*/class%20RunningCounter%20extends%20Counter{})
```

[image: Alt]